# Open dialog with JQuery UI

Tags: jquery-ui

I would like to open a JQuery UI dialog when a user clicks on a link. So far I have this

```
<script>
    //to hide the dialog box on loading
    $j(function() {
        $j( "#dialog" ).hide();
    });

    $('.button').click(function(){
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    });
</script>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>Dialog box</p>
</div>

<a href="#" class="button">The button</a>
```

But the dialog won't open by clicking the link... Everything is included well.

**EDIT**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script>
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/ui/jquery.effects.core.js"></script>
```

Comment: any errors in firebug console?? Its very hard to see what the error might be with the information you provided...

Comment: Sometimes you use `$` and sometimes `$j`. Is that on purpose?

Comment: @chelmertz, yes. I have conflicting libraries. That's why I sometimes use the $j

Answer (score 16):

Are you referencing jQuery and jQuery ui library? You can autohide when initializing:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false });


$('.button').click(function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pxQ8j/

Comment: A useful link and exactly what I want to achieve, but too bad. Not working :( Although I copied exactly what's stated on the link...

Comment: Does anything happen? Have you got jQuery AND jQuery-ui referenced on the page?

Comment: You're missing the position jQuery-ui file. I'm not sure if that's the problem, but the jQuery site states it's a [dependency](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/). Try go [here](http://jqueryui.com/download), deselect all, select dialog (which will automatically select the other scripts you need) and download. You should just need to reference it instead of core, widget and dialog. The downloaded file should include these.

Comment: makes perfect sense, but nothing... Absolutely nothing. The box isn't even hiding anymore!

Comment: Did you get your issue sorted..?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry for not replying. It appears to be a conflict with the JQUery lib's. I gave the project to a colleague and he told me he will fix it :) still don't get it, but thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code for your purpose.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Animation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "blind", 
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
      }
    });

    $( "#opener" ).on( "click", function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <form action="" method="post"> 
    Name  :- <input type="text" name="name" value="">
    Email :-<input type="email" name="email" value="">
    Submit:-<input id="dialog2" type="submit" onclick="myfuncation();" name="submit" value="save">
  </form>
</div>

<button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
<div id="dialog-message"></div>

</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myfuncation()
  {

      // Here is your ajax request to db related work.

      var ajaxresponce = "Sucessfully Insert Form";
      $('#dialog-message').html(ajaxresponce);
      $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog();

  }
</script>
```

Hope it helps you. Please let me know if you have any query.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you are trying to access the dialogs open method even though you never created the dialog instance.

Just change your code to do:

```
$('#dialog').dialog()
```

If you read the docs: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/, it spells that out for you, you will also see that it opens by default on the initial call.

Comment: Yes, I read the manual. I want the div to be closed on the initial call and to be opened when a user clicks the button...

Comment: If that is the case then Spencerooni's answer should solve your problem. You need to initialize it first then open it on the click.

Answer (score 1):

Notification dialog function like alert().

```
function msgbox(text,buttontext) {
    buttontext = buttontext || "OK"
    $( "<div>" + text + "</div>" ).dialog({
      dialogClass: "no-close",
      buttons: [
        {
          text: buttontext,
          click: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            $(this).remove();
          }
        }
      ]
    });
}
```

call function

```
msgbox("test dialog");
```

or

```
msgbox("test dialog", "I agree");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
.loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

/* Safari */
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
</style>
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Animation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "blind", 
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
      }
    });

    $( "#opener" ).on( "click", function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <form action="" method="post"> 
    Name  :- <input type="text" name="name" value="">
    Email :-<input type="email" name="email" value="">
<div id="test" class="loader"></div>

Submit:-<input id="dialog2" type="submit" onclick="myfuncation();" name="submit" value="save">
    
  </form>
</div>

<button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
<div id="dialog-message"></div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#test" ).hide();

function myfuncation()
  {
alert("hai");
      // Here is your ajax request to db related work.
$( "#test" ).show();
      //var ajaxresponce = "Sucessfully Insert Form";
      //$('#dialog-message').html(ajaxresponce);
     // $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog();

  }
</script>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation and do NOT just put a code snippet.